# TinyMCE and multiple CSS selectors on the parent css file handling

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I got a problem with TinyMCE when it comes to parent site CSS selectors.
My TinyMCE opens an iframe. I add the parent css to the tinyMCE via content_css property, no problem from there.

Now imagine that i got a css style like this:

```
.mysite.default .content h1 {
   ...
}

.mysite.default .info h4 {

}
```

The problem comes when i want to access to .content h1 or .info h4.
As by default, by adding to the body the class .mysite.default, if you got an h1 or h4, those won't be applied of course due to the selector .content and .info in the middle.

So inside the iframe's body i would be able to set styles only for

```
.mysite.default h1 { ... }

.mysite.default h4 { ... }
```

Is there a good strategy to have this kind of flexibility?

Problem is that I don't have only one h1 or h4 or span styling, I may got many of them, that's why I need a flexible selector strategy for this...

I can't just copy all the styles of the parent dynamically at runtime, because what if one of the parent selectors has a border, margins, padding (*because it might be a parent div wrapper container with some unique styling*) ?

So it's not that easy as saying, "hey add every parent style and that's all", because the child will have extra borders, extra margins when starting to edit that div.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to use

```
.mysite.default * h1 { ... }
```

to select all h1s inside other tags: the * wildcard covers any wrapping tag/class/id.

Hope that is helpful...!

Comment: mmmm but what if you want to keep the different containers with independent styles? If i use the * wildcard, all the h1 styles would be applied to that h1 im editing???

Comment: No one? :/ need help :(